# How to correctly bind Entity Framework to Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I want to do the following, bind OrderDetail to a DataGridView. Then all those OrderDetails add them to a single Order. How can i accomplish this. Not quite sure if i shall give more details.
**EDIT:** When making a new sale I have to create the sale and add the sale detail manually doing the mapping in the variable **c**, when I in theory could simply do a.Sales = ventaDetallesBindingSource.List

```
using (PuntoDeVentaEntities Entidades = new PuntoDeVentaEntities())
            {
                    Venta a = new Venta()
                    {
                        Fecha = DateTime.Now,
                    };
                    Entidades.AddToVentas(a);
                    Entidades.SaveChanges();
                    VentaDetalle c;

                    foreach (VentaDetalle item in ventaDetallesBindingSource.List)
                    {

                        c = new VentaDetalle()
                        {
                            IdProducto = item.IdProducto,
                            IdVenta = a.Id,
                            PrecioVenta = item.PrecioVenta,
                            Cantidad = item.Cantidad,
                            Producto = null,
                            Venta = null,
                            IdCliente = item.IdCliente,
                            Cliente = null
                        };

                        a.VentaDetalles.Add(c);
                        c = null;

                    }


                    Entidades.SaveChanges();
```

}

Comment: Could you explain what want you to get exactly (more detail) ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!